# Which tools for my first mobile application

Tags: mobile

I'm about to start building my first mobile app and wanted some direction. The app will need to:

- run on iPhone, Windows Phone, and Android
- access data from a database
- be able to determine where it is (e.g., when I cross a state border, when I enter a city, or, generally, when I change locales)
- the GUI will be relatively straightforward

After doing a bit of research, I have a few questions:

- Should I use a framework (e.g., Rho, Appcelerator, or PhoneGap) or HTML5/CSS3/JS? Or, would I use both of those in combination?
- I want to sell the app, so does that preclude building it as a website (i.e., HTML5/CSS3/JS)? In other words, if I build it as a website, doesn't that mean a user won't have to download it and install it like a native mobile app? I like the idea of making it a "native" mobile app vs. a website, although maybe I shouldn't.
- Is REST the best way to access my data? My thought is to have a SQL Server database and build a REST service using .NET.

And other tips or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Jay

Comment: This question is **huge**, SO is designed for specific questions related to programming problems rather than discussions about frameworks and development processes. Please read [the FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) for tips on asking questions.

Comment: You're asking multiple questions at once (not recommended) and all of your questions are inviting discussion and/or argument.  Please read the FAQ about how to ask a good SO question.

Comment: If you are going to *start*, you should first try with one of the platforms and feel how it is the app development.

Comment: Thanks to @TomWalters and Jason regarding proper etiquette. I appreciate it. And thanks for the tip, eLRuLL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a tool such as Appcelerator then you the end product will be native.  Appcelerator framework obfuscates the underlying native interfaces for android/iOS.  There are a few instances where you'll need to know the differences between the two, for example when to use what Appcelerator class for each device, but in essence, you can write once and deploy to each device.  Been using it  for a while and is very nice. Appcelerator will give you all the hooks you need to tap into the devices natively.

PhoneGap will just wrap up your app and create a 'web app'.  Basically a packaged website.  IMO Appcelerator would be the way to go.  This is more similar to your second bullet.  You'll build the website, you just won't host it on a server.  It will be packaged up and deployed to the device. In essence the phone becomes the 'web server' but only in the sense that the device is reading web pages that are local to the device.

As far as data, REST might be the best way to go.  the calls would be quick.  You may not really need to build your own DB.  You might want to look and see if some of the data you are going to use is already out there.  Unless you are collecting data.  I don't know the details of your app so I'm not sure what help this opinion provides.

Hope this helps.

Comment: So it sounds like even if I wrote the "app" in HTML/CSS/JS, it would install and run as a "native app." Did I understand that correctly? That's definitely helpful. And yes, there will be a corresponding website where data will be collected, so a dedicated database will be necessary. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Not necessarily. "Native" means that it's going to access the device directly.  So when you write code in Appcelerator to use the GPS hardware on the device, you'll actually be using it.  If you write in HTML/CSS/JS, then you won't be.  The HTML/CSS/JS way of packaging a deploying the app is sorta a 'quick and dirty' way to get an app out there.  Not that this is bad. There are many apps out there like this.

Comment: Great! Thanks, Alex. Sounds like I'm going to want focus more on the native app route, which is what I was already thinking. I appreciate your help!